# Linked list using unique pointers won't run as I expected

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list using unique pointers, something that I have done million times in c, but it seems that I can not make it work! The problem probably relies on the use of unique pointers but I'm not certain why.

In the following code you will notice two things. A **class Node** which contains the data of each element in the list and a **class LinkedList** which implements the behavior of the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Node
{

//Private variables.
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next; //Next node.
    std::unique_ptr<Node> prev; //Previous node.


    //Int value.
    int value;



//Public variables.
public:

    //Constructor.
    Node(int v)
    :next(nullptr), prev(nullptr), value(v)
    {
    }


    //Set next node.
    void set_next(std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node)
    {
       next = std::move(new_node);
    }


    //Set previous node.
    void set_prev(std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node)
    {
        prev = std::move(new_node);
    }


    //Set value.
    void set_value(int v)
    {
        value = v;
    }


    //Get next node.
    std::unique_ptr<Node> get_next()
    {
        return std::move(next);
    }


    //Get previous node.
    std::unique_ptr<Node> get_prev()
    {
        return std::move(prev);
    }


    //Get value.
    int get_value()
    {
        return value;
    }



};


class LinkedList
{

//Private variables.
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tail;



//Public variables.
public:

    //Constructor.
    LinkedList()
    :head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
    {
    }


    //Append a item to the list.
    void append(int v)
    {

        //Creating a new node.
        std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node( new Node(v) );


        //If this is the very first node.
        if (head == nullptr || tail == nullptr)
            {
                head = std::move(new_node);
                tail = std::move(new_node);
            }



        //Append.
        else
            {
                tail -> set_next( std::move(new_node) ); //Linking the new node.
                new_node -> set_prev( std::move(tail) ); //Set the previous.
                tail = std::move(new_node);              //Update the tail.
            }

    }


    //Print all the elements.
    void print()
    {

        //Starting node.
        std::unique_ptr<Node>curr = std::move(head);


        //While Loop.
        while(curr != nullptr)
            {
                cout << curr -> get_value() << endl;
                curr = std::move( curr -> get_next() );
            }
    }

};


int main()
{
LinkedList myList;

myList.append(1);
myList.append(2);
myList.append(3);
myList.append(4);

myList.print();

return 0;
}
```

Output should be 1,2,3,4 but instead it's only 4!
I did debugging and i found out the following statement
is running 4 times:

```
            //If this is the very first node.
        if (head == nullptr || tail == nullptr)
            {
                head = std::move(new_node);
                tail = std::move(new_node);
            }
```

But why? The first time, **head** and **tail** will be null
but after that they will point somewhere so this statement should never
run again.

Comment: Multiple unique pointers cannot point to the same object, and once a unique pointer has been moved to another unique pointer, the original no longer points to the object.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, and examine the pointers as you move them around to see that they don't match your expectations.

Comment: Answering a quick question posed in a comment to a deleted answer: Should I create data structures like this in C++? Answer 1: Rarely. The standard library already includes a list structure that does almost exactly this. Why reinvent the wheel? Answer 2: I'd do it a bit differently. If you make `Node` a private class inside `LinkedList` and never expose it to users you can save yourself a lot of effort you've devoted to protecting `node`. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234616/linked-list-private-pointers-c/38235373#38235373

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One fundamental property of a `std::unique_ptr` is that only one `std::unique_ptr` can own a given pointer, at the same time. This happens to be what the "unique" part is all about.

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node( new Node(v) );
```

Ok. So far so good.

```
   head = std::move(new_node);
   tail = std::move(new_node);
```

And that's your problem. You're trying to move the same `std::unique_ptr` into two others. That won't work. Only one of them can own a pointer.

Replace all your `std::unique_ptr`s with `std::shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Recommend a slight tweak: Worth pointing out that `std::shared_ptr` eliminates the need for `std::move`.

Comment: Ok problem solved. I also want to ask: Should i create my data structures in c++ using smart pointers? In c i was handling the memory with the free() and malloc() functions. In c++ i found some posts saying is not good to use the 'new' keyword to store new objects into pointers and then delete them because of exception problems.

Comment: @babaliaris in C++ only use `malloc` and `free` in rare edge cases. Use `new` and `delete` instead because they know how to do constructors and destructors. Can using `new` and `delete` lead to problems? You betcha! Avoid where possible, but... A linked list is not a place where you can conveniently avoid it. Pretty much the point of having students write a linked list is to force them to learn to use pointers correctly and carefully. A shared pointer is not the right choice here. Shared pointer is when you have multiple competing owners of an object. Here the linked list is the owner.

Comment: `shared_ptr` works, but it's ideologically incorrect. `unique_ptr` also does not quite work because you any one node could be at the receiving end of a previous and a next. This is a job for raw pointers and a carefully written `LinkedList` class that makes certain that nodes are created and disposed of as required and never exposed to the `LinkedList`'s user.

Comment: i see... I know how to use pointers, `new` and `delete` to create data structures (is excactly the same with c where i used `malloc` and `free`).
What i afraid of is that when you use `new` and `delete` you may have
some leaks in memory because of exceptions like "out of memory" (At least thats what they said to me).
How can i handle that? What more should i be aware of when using 
`new` and `delete`? Also if you know a good guide about this, a link would be nice :p

Comment: Εventually i found this link: [Dynamic Memory Allocation With new and delete](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/)  which was extremly usefull :p